Dynamic access based on crirteria on parent object
I have a master-detail relationship where CustomA is the parent and CustomB is the child.
In the profile, CustomA has read access, while CustomB has read, create, and edit access. The OWD is set to private.
A user will manually share the record with another user with read-only access.
I want to grant edit access on the child record only when the parent's status field has the value "New." and restrict edit access it status has any other value.
How can I achieve this?

Do you have checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.security_sharing_rules_criteria.htm&type=5  -https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rules_criteria.htm

Hi @TusharJadav,
User sharing record using manual share shall we enforce that using sharing rules?

Hi @TusharJadav,
If i allow public read/write it will give access to parent and child inherits the same access, but i want to give only edit access to child.

@TusharJadav you're right, the current configuration won't support the requirement to dynamically provide that access. You've got two options, either change the relationship to be a Lookup rather than Master-Detail or allow the access but add a validation rule that prevents any edits unless it is in the New status.
